# Travis CI: Build failure on timeout. License not accepted?

Tags: android, travis-ci

My build fails in Travis CI. It does not accept Android SDK License:

```
 $ sdkmanager "system-images;android-28;google_apis;x86"
 Warning: File /home/travis/.android/repositories.cfg could not be loaded.   
 License android-sdk-license:
 ---------------------------------------
 Terms and Conditions
    .
    .
    . //bunch of terms here
    .
    .
  Accept? (y/N):
```

My Travis yml file:

```
sudo: required
language: android
jdk: oraclejdk8
android:
  components:
    - tools
    - tools
    - platform-tools
    - build-tools-28.0.3
    - android-28
    - add-on
    - extra
before_install:
    - echo yes | sdkmanager "build-tools;28.0.3"
    - echo yes | sdkmanager "platforms;android-28"
    - mkdir "$ANDROID_HOME/licenses" || true
    - echo -e "\n8933bad161af4178b1185d1a37fbf41ea5269c55" > "$ANDROID_HOME/licenses/android-sdk-license"
    - echo -e "\n84831b9409646a918e30573bab4c9c91346d8abd" > "$ANDROID_HOME/licenses/android-sdk-preview-license"
    - sdkmanager "system-images;android-28;google_apis;x86"
    - echo no | avdmanager create avd --force -n emulatorApi28 -k "system-images;android-28;google_apis;x86"
    - emulator -avd test -no-audio -no-window &
    - ./gradlew dependencies || true
before_script:
    - android-wait-for-emulator
    - adb shell input keyevent 82 &
script:
    - ./gradlew build connectedCheck
    - "./gradlew clean build connectedCheck -PdisablePreDex --stacktrace"
before_cache:
    - $HOME/.gradle/caches/
    - $HOME/.gradle/wrapper/
    - $HOME/.android/build-cache
cache:
    directories:
        -$HOME/.gradle/caches/
        -$HOME/.gradle/wrapper/s
licenses:
    - 'android-sdk-preview-license-.+'
    - 'android-sdk-license-.+'
    - 'google-gdk-license-.+'
```

Any suggestions?

**EDIT**:

```
sudo: required
language: android
jdk: oraclejdk8
android:
    licenses:
    - 'android-sdk-preview-license-.+'
    - 'android-sdk-license-.+'
    - 'google-gdk-license-.+' 
  components:
    - tools
    - tools
    - platform-tools
    - build-tools-28.0.3
    - android-28
    - add-on
    - extra
before_install:
    - echo y | sdkmanager "build-tools;28.0.3"
    - echo y | sdkmanager "platforms;android-28"
    - mkdir "$ANDROID_HOME/licenses" || true
    - echo -e "\n8933bad161af4178b1185d1a37fbf41ea5269c55" > "$ANDROID_HOME/licenses/android-sdk-license"
    - echo -e "\    " > "$ANDROID_HOME/licenses/android-sdk-preview-license"
    - sdkmanager "system-images;android-28;google_apis;x86"
    - echo no | avdmanager create avd --force -n emulatorApi28 -k "system-images;android-28;google_apis;x86"
    - emulator -avd test -no-audio -no-window &
    - ./gradlew dependencies || true
before_script:
    - android-wait-for-emulator
    - adb shell input keyevent 82 &
script:
    - ./gradlew build connectedCheck
    - "./gradlew clean build connectedCheck -PdisablePreDex --stacktrace"
before_cache:
    - $HOME/.gradle/caches/
    - $HOME/.gradle/wrapper/
    - $HOME/.android/build-cache
cache:
    directories:
        -$HOME/.gradle/caches/
        -$HOME/.gradle/wrapper/sis?
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/android/), the `licenses` part should be under the `android` part. So it should be like this:

```
android:
  components:
  ...
  licenses:
    - 'android-sdk-preview-license-.+'
    - 'android-sdk-license-.+'
    - 'google-gdk-license-.+'
```

Comment: Thanks, I did try this now, the problem is that it does not trigger a build in Travis when I commit to repo. Any ideas on why?

Comment: Make sure that licenses is under Android: not components. Also, for your sdkmanager commands, try `echo y` instead of `echo yes`. To check why Travis doesn't build, go to you project in Travis, and check under requests

Comment: No requests are made to Travis even though I made commits and pushed to my public github. It stopped sending to travis when I moved my licenses to under android. Do you have any ideas on why? I edited my question and added my travis.yml file. I even tried with "y" instead of yes.

Comment: Are you sure you checked the requests tab instead of the usual build history or dashboard? Sometimes if there's something wrong with the configuration file, it'll only appear in the requests tab but not the build history part